# nltk NgramModel error

Tags: python, nltk

I've previously used the `NgramModel` class in nltk without error. However, I recently updated nltk to [version 3.1](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/ChangeLog) and I can no longer find the `NgramModel` class. When I try to import as usual:

`from nltk.model import NgramModel`

I get the error

`ImportError: No module named 'nltk.model'`.

Has `NgramModel` or the `model` module been recently replaced?

Comment: Until the NgramModel is stablized, you can try https://github.com/kpu/kenlm and its python wrapper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an [open issue](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/738) because of [bugs](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/labels/model).

This is noted in the issue:

> If you're currently using the version from github, you can switch to the "model" branch, which includes the NgramModel code, though it's currently significantly behind the "develop" branch and hasn't picked up all the newest bug fixes.

The link to the model branch is [here](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/tree/model).

Comment: Thanks! Because of the bugs, would you recommend switching to another module with the same language model capabilities?

Comment: @istewart If the bugs didn't bother you, you could probably just add the `model` module to your local installation of NLTK. This way you'll have both new NLTK features and the `NGramModel` that you want. YMMV, though.

Comment: Update: I just updated as expected and now `NgramModel` imports fine. However, after building a language model, I tried to calculate the entropy and got the following error:
  
`File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/model/ngram.py", line 171, in prob
    return self._probdist.prob((context, word))
AttributeError: 'NgramModel' object has no attribute '_probdist'`  

So I think I'll be using another language model class, if possible.